# Linear Algebra solving for x,y,z in a system

Tags: linear-algebra

Question 3: (6 pts) A company makes 3 kinds of snacks, using almonds and raisins. The Fruity snack
contains 100g of almonds and 300g of raisins. The Nutty snack contains 300g of almonds and 100g of
raisins. The Variety snack contains 200g of almonds and 200g of raisins. There are currently 900g of
almonds and 700g of raisins available, and we want to determine how many of each kind of snacks can be
made so that all the ingredients are completely used.
a) Define variables and set up a linear system in order to solve the problem.
b) Find all the realistic solutions to the problem.

I answered A)

```
100x + 300y + 200z = 900

300x + 100y + 200z = 700
```

How do I do B)?

Comment: Worded a different way, you have the following matrix equation:  $\begin{bmatrix} 100&300&200\\300&100&200\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}900\\700\end{bmatrix}$  It is asking you to solve the matrix equation, which should be a known process to you in a linear algebra course (keeping in mind that it doesn't make sense to sell a negative amount of a specific type of snack).

Comment: Regarding b)  you have 3 variables and 2 unknowns.  If you were to solve this over a solution set defined over the real numbers, there would be a line of potential solutions.  However, "realistic solutions" will restrict the solutions to the natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify, divide both equations by $100$, solve the first for $x$ to get $$x = 9 - 3y - 2z$$ and plug it into the second one to eliminate $x$, and solve the second for $y$ in terms of $z$.

Then, find a range for $z$ which results in realistic values for all 3 components.

Comment: The answer is (1,2,1) and (0,1,3). how do they get two results?

Comment: @RajaSharma You know that $x, y, z \geq 0$, and therefore $x < 9$ by the equation in the answer. Therefore, plug in from $x=0$ to $x=8$ into the two equations and solve for $x$ and $y$. The solutions from $x=2$ to $x=8$ are probably excluded because they make $y$ and $z$ negative or non-integers.